# How to import two dependent python files?

Tags: python-2.7

I have created PYDEV project, with in this I have some folder like **A & B**. In A module there is `demo1.py` file and in B there is `demo2.py` and also which is importing `demo1` file from **A**.

So I need to import `demo2.py`, at that time I am facing an error:

```
from A import demo1
```

Throwing error as

> no module named A

how can we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found out the answer

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./A')
from A import demo1
```

Now it is working.